# Why won't my promise reject successfully?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I want the error to be caught successfully. I don't know why it won't catch. I tried adding more conditionals to the promise but they didn't work. I would like the error to be caught and logged to the console.

```
const betterChore = (chore) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(chore !== undefined || chore !== null) {
        res("I have to " + chore);
      } else {
        rej(Error("Need to specify a chore."));
      }
    }, 2000)
  })
}

const doTasks = async (task) => {
  let chore = await betterChore(task);
  return chore;
}

doTasks("")
  .then(item => {
    console.log(item);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("We are done here!")
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
  })
```

Comment: `chore !== undefined || chore !== null` will always be true.

Comment: The `if` statement in your `betterChore()` function is wrong. Your code resolves the promise when `chore` is *either* not `undefined` or not `null`, and that will always be `true`.

Comment: You might prefer `chore !== undefined && chore !== null`, but it's probably easier to read if you swap the logic and reject under a positive test: `if (chore == undefined) { reject()}`.

Comment: Or just `chore != null`.

Comment: Simple mistake. All fixed, thanks everyone :)